# Upload File/Image with class Storage Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

First, I'm sorry for my bad English.

I want to upload a file/image from my driver to my project directory using class *`Storage`*. I want that every file/image will be uploaded/moved to my `public/img` directory. I use `Form::file('img')` on my views and on my post controller, I write this

```
 $img = Input::file('img');
    if ($img !== null) {
        $filename       = $img->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $filename);

        $jenis->img     = $filename;  
    }
```

and on my *`config/filesystem`* I write this

```
'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/img',
    ],
```

But, nothing happen on my *`public/img`* directory, no new file/image on there.
Can u help me whats wrong with my code?
and I hope u guys can help me with another good way on how to upload a file/image in laravel

Comment: Need help [Mr. Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2781542/jacurtis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your problem is you're not storing the file, you're referencing its name not its contents.

Try this:

```
Storage::disk('uploads') -> put($filename, file_get_contents($img -> getRealPath()));
```

Comment: Thanks [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625407/matt-mcdonald)
It works, but I dont really undestand what happen on that put(). Can u explain to me? Thanks

Comment: @DarmaKurniawanHarefa The first argument passed to `put` is the full path for the file (as you've set a default folder in the config this can just be the name of the file if you don't want it in a subfolder). The second argument is the contents of the file. So using the php `file_get_contents` function you're passing the file's contents to the Storage `put` method. The `getRealPath` method on your input file passes the real path of the temporary file that's been uploaded to your server.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

In my filesystem file I configure my image directory in this way:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path("/img"),
],
```

I think that you can use your way but is another point.

To get the file from your view you should use File::get Laravel function:

```
$filename = $img->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::disk('uploads')->put($filename, \File::get($file));
```

With this would be enough, you save the file with the name of file uploaded in directory specify in filesystem.

Comment: Thanks [Juan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5560051/juan-manuel-barea-mart%c3%adnez) but class File dosnt work for me. Need to define/use a File class?

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary, but try to define in this way: ´use Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem´ in your controller. Anyway, what error show you laravel?

Comment: \File::get($file); is that file or img?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ($request->hasFile('original_pic')) {
            $original_pic = $request->file('original_pic');

            $file_extension=$original_pic>getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $file_extension;

            # upload original image
            Storage::put('ArticlesImages/' . $filename, (string) file_get_contents($original_pic), 'public');

            # croped image from request.
            $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->input('article_image'));
            $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

            Storage::put('ArticlesImages/croped/' . $filename, (string) $image_base64, 'public');

            # get image from s3 or local storage.
            $image_get = Storage::get('ArticlesImages/croped/' . $filename);

            # resize 50 by 50 1x
            $image_50_50 = Image::make($image_get)
                    ->resize(340, 227)
                    ->encode($file_extension, 80);

            Storage::put('ArticlesImages/1x/' . $filename, (string) $image_50_50, 'public');

            $file_url = Storage::url('ArticlesImages/croped/' . $filename);

            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'filename' => $filename, 'file_url' => $file_url], 200);
        }
```